# Django STATIC FILES not loading in actual Production

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-media

I have tried many things to solve this like adding `whitenoise` middleware, also added STATICFILES_DIRS = [], added mimetypes for css
in settings.py file CSS/JS Won't load.

Here is my settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import environ
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

STRIPE_PUB_KEY = env('STRIPE_PUB_KEY') 

DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'users',
    'addresses',
    'orders',
    'feedback',
    'message',
    'gifts_coupons',
    'core',
    'product',
    'fulfillment',
    'cart',
    'discounts',
    'stripe_pay',
    
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'django_filters',
    'creditcards',
    'mptt',
    'corsheaders',
    'import_export',
    'django_inlinecss',
]

IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS = True

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True 

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://estreetmart.in',
    'https://estreetmart.sg',
    'https://ims.estreetmart.in',
    'http://localhost:8000',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'orders.middlewares.cart_middleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'estreetmart.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'estreetmart.wsgi.application'
...
```

I also added following in my main urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

but still css/js is not loading so I inspected the code and found following:
 [403 Forbidden error for static file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD2Zj.png)

and also sources is empty:
[Sources are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ7dK.png)

Comment: Did you get this issue sorted out? In case you didn't share your project file structure. Usually, the Static files are contained in any one of your applications within Django. Having them at the base directory caused these issues for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in my Nginx server file I commented following section and it worked

```
location /static/ {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For static files use `STATIC_URL` and  `STATIC_ROOT`. Add to your main `urls.py`

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: I'm afraid, I already mentioned that I have above code in place

Comment: You mention about `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` which is used for media files and I mention about `STATIC_URL`  and `STATIC_ROOT` which is used for serving static files.

Comment: Still the same result I don't see css loading

Comment: Set `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your `settings.py` and run `python manage.py collectstatic`.